# AWS Athena: Delete partitions between date range

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I have an athena table with partition based on date like this:

```
20190218
```

I want to delete all the partitions that are created last year.

I tried the below query, but it didnt work.

```
ALTER TABLE tblname DROP PARTITION (partition1 < '20181231');

ALTER TABLE tblname DROP PARTITION (partition1 > '20181010'), Partition (partition1 < '20181231');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/alter-table-drop-partition.html, `ALTER TABLE tblname DROP PARTITION` takes a partition spec, so no ranges are allowed.

In Presto you would do `DELETE FROM tblname WHERE ...`, but `DELETE` is not supported by Athena either.

For these reasons, you need to do leverage some external solution.

For example:

1. list the files as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48824373/65458
2. delete the files and containing directories
3. update partitions information (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/msck-repair-table.html should be helpful)

Comment: Also important to note that `alter table drop partition` will not delete any data, just the partition meta-data object.  Deleting the files is an independent operation and could be done in any order if required.

Comment: @Davos, I think this is true for external tables.

Comment: I used the aws cli to retrieve the partitions. Then I used a bash script to run aws cli commands to drop the partition if it was older than some date.

Answer (score 3):

While the Athena SQL may not support it at this time, the Glue API call `GetPartitions` (that Athena uses under the hood for queries) supports complex filter expressions similar to what you can write in a SQL `WHERE` expression.

Instead of deleting partitions through Athena you can do [`GetPartitions`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-catalog-partitions.html#aws-glue-api-catalog-partitions-GetPartitions) followed by [`BatchDeletePartition`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-catalog-partitions.html#aws-glue-api-catalog-partitions-BatchDeletePartition) using the Glue API.

Comment: That is a super interesting answer, thanks for sharing Theo!

Comment: has anyone got a script to share in e.g. python for this? Thanks if someone can share.

Answer (score 2):

this is the script the does what Theo recommended.

```py
import json
import logging

import awswrangler as wr
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format=logging.BASIC_FORMAT)
logger = logging.getLogger()


def delete_partitions(database_name: str, table_name: str):
  client = boto3.client('glue')
  paginator = client.get_paginator('get_partitions')
  page_count = 0
  partition_count = 0
  for page in paginator.paginate(DatabaseName=database_name, TableName=table_name, MaxResults=20):
    page_count = page_count + 1
    partitions = page['Partitions']
    partitions_to_delete = []
    for partition in partitions:
      partition_count = partition_count + 1
      partitions_to_delete.append({'Values': partition['Values']})
      logger.info(f"Found partition {partition['Values']}")
    if partitions_to_delete:
      response = client.batch_delete_partition(DatabaseName=database_name, TableName=table_name,
        PartitionsToDelete=partitions_to_delete)
      logger.info(f'Deleted partitions with response: {response}')
    else:
      logger.info('Done with all partitions')


def repair_table(database_name: str, table_name: str):
  client = boto3.client('athena')
  try:
    response = client.start_query_execution(QueryString='MSCK REPAIR TABLE ' + table_name + ';',
      QueryExecutionContext={'Database': database_name}, )
  except ClientError as err:
    logger.info(err.response['Error']['Message'])
  else:
    res = wr.athena.wait_query(query_execution_id=response['QueryExecutionId'])
    logger.info(f"Query succeeded: {json.dumps(res, indent=2)}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
  table = 'table_name'
  database = 'database_name'
  delete_partitions(database_name=database, table_name=table)
  repair_table(database_name=database, table_name=table)
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting the Glue API workaround for Java to save some time for these who need it:

```
public void deleteMetadataTablePartition(String catalog,
                                         String db,
                                         String table,
                                         String expression) {

    GetPartitionsRequest getPartitionsRequest = new GetPartitionsRequest()
            .withCatalogId(catalog)
            .withDatabaseName(db)
            .withTableName(table)
            .withExpression(expression);

    List<PartitionValueList> partitionsToDelete = new ArrayList<>();

    do {
        GetPartitionsResult getPartitionsResult = this.glue.getPartitions(getPartitionsRequest);
        List<PartitionValueList> partitionsValues = getPartitionsResult.getPartitions()
                .parallelStream()
                .map(p -> new PartitionValueList().withValues(p.getValues()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        partitionsToDelete.addAll(partitionsValues);

        getPartitionsRequest.setNextToken(getPartitionsResult.getNextToken());
    } while (getPartitionsRequest.getNextToken() != null);

    Lists.partition(partitionsToDelete, 25)
            .parallelStream()
            .forEach(partitionValueList -> {
                glue.batchDeletePartition(
                        new BatchDeletePartitionRequest()
                                .withCatalogId(catalog)
                                .withDatabaseName(db)
                                .withTableName(table)
                                .withPartitionsToDelete(partitionValueList));
            });
}
```