# Amazon Athena: How to drop all partitions at once

Tags: amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

**My partitions look like these**

```
event_year=2019/event_week=37/event_date=2019-09-10
event_year=2019/event_week=42/event_date=2019-10-13
event_year=2019/event_week=8/event_date=2019-02-20
event_year=2020/event_week=24/event_date=2020-06-15
```

There are 1500 partitions like this how do I drop all the partitions at once?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/68249507/7407116. That worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest and quickest way is to drop the table and recreate it. You can get the DDL with `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` if you don't have it.

If you really need to drop partitions and not the table the most efficient way is to use the Glue Data Catalog APIs to first [list all partitions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-catalog-partitions.html#aws-glue-api-catalog-partitions-GetPartitions) and then [delete partitions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-catalog-partitions.html#aws-glue-api-catalog-partitions-BatchDeletePartition) in batches of 25.

Answer (score 1):

It's not documented anywhere but *sometimes* in athena you can drop all partitions with

`ALTER TABLE table_name DROP PARTITION (not_a_column=NULL)`

This appears to be a side effect of being able to only specify one partition if you have a table partitioned on multiple dimensions.

If the above doesn't work then I fallback to using the `awswrangler` python library https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubs/awswrangler.catalog.delete_partitions.html

Comment: Seems like this answer is sent just for me. Thanks for your contribution.